# Maven Exception While installing the WSO2 ESB Project in developer studio

Tags: maven, ubuntu, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am using Developer Studio 3.7.0.  I have made a simple ESB project, containing one simple proxy service. But When i maven build the project by using the "clean install" command. I get the following error. I have literally no idea what is wrong.

**Note:**

I have made a new VM on my machine and I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on it. Outside the VM on my root OS(ubuntu 12.04) the developer studio works fine but inside the VM it is not working. I think i am missing some component.
**Error:**

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (install) on project TestVM: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/home/omerkhalid/workspace/TestVM/target/capp"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (install) on project TestVM: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/home/omerkhalid/workspace/TestVM/target/capp"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:246)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:302)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:589)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:335)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
        ... 28 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Maven cannot find itself to execute a sub-process. It may be the environment variables are not getting copied to the new shell.

Comment: so what should i do??

Comment: can you run mvn from the command line in the virtual machine?

Comment: I have reinstalled the maven in my machine and my problem is solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems you are building inside the target directory, "/home/omerkhalid/workspace/TestVM/target/capp". If I am not mistaken you need to build it inside "/home/omerkhalid/workspace/TestVM/" where the project root.